# String que contenga cualquier letra unicode en mayusculas

Tags: javascript, regex

Intento crear un regex en javascript que detecte si el string contiene algún caracter en mayúsculas para todos los idiomas.

He probado con el modificador `/u` pero no funciona, empiezo a creer que esto no es posible de forma sencilla.

No me interesa guarrear el código con todos los caracteres de todos los idiomas.

```js
const string01 = "ñ Ñ ç Ç";
const string02 = "ñ Ñ ç Ç A";

const regex = /[A-Z]/gu

console.log(regex.test(string01)) // false
console.log(regex.test(string02)) // true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que en este caso particular no es muy sencillo usando regex, creo que un enfoque posible es verificando cada letra con la misma letra `.toUpperCase()` y solo comparando letras de cualquier lenguage sacando todo lo demás con `/[^\p{L}]/gmu`:

```js
const string01 = "ñ a ç Ç";
const string02 = "ñ a ç á a & % 1123";

const regex = /[^\p{L}]/gmu;

const tiene_mayuscula = (str) => [...str].some(l=> l === l.replace(regex,"").toUpperCase());

console.log(tiene_mayuscula(string01));// <-- tiene alguna mayúscula

console.log(tiene_mayuscula(string02));// <-- no tiene ninguna mayúscula
```

`\p{L}` se usa para detectar cualquier letra de cualquier lenguaje si se usa con el flag `u`. Todo dentro de `[^]` es para que seleccione todo menos lo que está dentro (cualquier letra de cualquier lenguaje).

Answer (score 3):

El problema con tu regex es que [A-Z] no incluye las letras que no son comunes en todos los alfabetos latinos: la Ñ, la Ç, las vocales con acentos, diéresis o umlauts...

```js
const string01 = "ñ Ñ ç Ç";
const string02 = "ñ Ñ ç Ç A";

const regex = /[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚÜÑÇ]/g

console.log(regex.test(string01)) // false
console.log(regex.test(string02)) // true
```

Para cada idioma que quieras soportar tendrías que ampliar esta expresión regular.

Otra opción sería comprobar que cada caracter está o no en mayúsculas:

```js
function isUppercase(char) {
  // los espacios, las comas... se quedan igual, por tanto tenemos que comprobar que están en mayúsculas y NO en minúsculas.
  return char === char.toUpperCase() && char !== char.toLowerCase(); 
}

const test = "es una prueba con una Ñ";
const test2 = "es otra prueba con una ñ";

console.log(test.split('').some(isUppercase));
console.log(test2.split('').some(isUppercase));
```